# Launch Android email client in Unity, specifying recipient, subject, and body as intent extras... getting NoSuchFieldError

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine

I'm attempting to launch Android's email client (well, technically, whatever the user decides to pick when prompted, but really... the email client) from within Unity Player to allow the user to send email with the recipient, subject, and body pre-populated (they can edit it if they want, but the expectation is that they'll usually just fire it off as-is).

I got the following code to work... but ONLY when the line that sets the EXTRA_EMAIL parameter is commented out. Otherwise, it throws a NoSuchFieldError

```cs
        AndroidJavaClass intentClass = new AndroidJavaClass("android.content.Intent");
        AndroidJavaObject intentObject = new AndroidJavaObject("android.content.Intent");

        string[] recipient = { "bugreport@mydomain.net" };
        string subject = "bug report";
        string body = errorDump();
        
        intentObject.Call<AndroidJavaObject>("setAction", intentClass.GetStatic<string>("ACTION_SENDTO"));
        intentObject.Call<AndroidJavaObject>("setType", "text/plain");

        // intentObject.Call<AndroidJavaObject>("putExtra", intentClass.GetStatic<string[]>("EXTRA_EMAIL"), recipient);
        intentObject.Call<AndroidJavaObject>("putExtra", intentClass.GetStatic<string>("EXTRA_SUBJECT"), subject);
        intentObject.Call<AndroidJavaObject>("putExtra", intentClass.GetStatic<string>("EXTRA_TEXT"), body);

        AndroidJavaClass unity = new AndroidJavaClass("com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer");
        AndroidJavaObject currentActivity = unity.GetStatic<AndroidJavaObject>("currentActivity");
        currentActivity.Call("startActivity", intentObject);
```

As far as I can tell, I've done everything correctly...

- GetStatic specifies a `<string[]>`? Check.
- The field's name is `EXTRA_EMAIL`? Check.
- "recipient" **is** a `string[]` (with exactly one element)? Check.

What am I doing wrong? According to Google's official docs at https://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-common#Email , EXTRA_EMAIL *is* a valid field type for ACTION_SENDTO.

---

**Update:** the accepted answer is correct, but fixing this problem uncovered a new problem that I was able to resolve on my own.

Basically, I misread the originally commented-out line. **recipient** is (rightfully) a string[], but the `<string>` in `GetStatic<String>` is telling the compiler that the literal "ACTION_SENDTO" is a string, not that **recipient** is a string).

The story didn't quite end there. From my reading of Google's docs, I was under the impression that ACTION_SENDTO is intended for straightforward plaintext email, and ACTION_SEND is intended for email with a single attachment.

In reality, it appears that neither GMail nor any other mail client on my phone registers itself as an intent handler for ACTION_SENDTO... only ACTION_SEND. When I attempted to start an activity for ACTION_SENDTO, I got "No activity found to handle intent". Changing it to ACTION_SEND fixed the problem.

Apparently, ACTION_SEND *allows* you to specify an attachment, but doesn't *require* it... and many/most/all Android email clients no longer bother to declare themselves as handlers for ACTION_SENDTO.

## Correct version of the original code:

```cs
        AndroidJavaClass intentClass = new AndroidJavaClass("android.content.Intent");
        AndroidJavaObject intentObject = new AndroidJavaObject("android.content.Intent");

        string[] recipient = { "bugreport@mydomain.net" };
        string subject = "bug report";
        string body = errorDump();
        
        /* fixed, is now ACTION_SEND */
        intentObject.Call<AndroidJavaObject>("setAction", intentClass.GetStatic<string>("ACTION_SEND"));
        intentObject.Call<AndroidJavaObject>("setType", "text/plain");

        /* fixed, now has GetStatic<string>("EXTRA_EMAIL") */
        intentObject.Call<AndroidJavaObject>("putExtra", intentClass.GetStatic<string>("EXTRA_EMAIL"), recipient);
        intentObject.Call<AndroidJavaObject>("putExtra", intentClass.GetStatic<string>("EXTRA_SUBJECT"), subject);
        intentObject.Call<AndroidJavaObject>("putExtra", intentClass.GetStatic<string>("EXTRA_TEXT"), body);

        AndroidJavaClass unity = new AndroidJavaClass("com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer");
        AndroidJavaObject currentActivity = unity.GetStatic<AndroidJavaObject>("currentActivity");
        currentActivity.Call("startActivity", intentObject);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You said that the NoSuchFieldError errror is happening here:

```
intentObject.Call<AndroidJavaObject>("putExtra", intentClass.GetStatic<string[]>("EXTRA_EMAIL"), recipient);
```

It can't find `EXTRA_EMAIL` because on the [Android doc](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent#EXTRA_EMAIL),  the `EXTRA_EMAIL` variable is declared as a simple string:

```
public static final String EXTRA_EMAIL
```

but you're searching as a string array when you did:

```
intentClass.GetStatic<string[]>("EXTRA_EMAIL")
```

Notice the `[]` you added next the `string`.

This would have worked if `EXTRA_EMAIL` was also declared as an array like this:

```
public static final String[] EXTRA_EMAIL
```

but it's not so remove the `[]` or replace:

```
intentObject.Call<AndroidJavaObject>("putExtra", intentClass.GetStatic<string[]>("EXTRA_EMAIL"), recipient);
```

with

```
intentObject.Call<AndroidJavaObject>("putExtra", intentClass.GetStatic<string>("EXTRA_EMAIL"), recipient);
```